# Firebase many to many relationship retrieve data

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have the following data structure , users and services have many to many 
relationship

```
users : {
  user1 : {
    name : blah,
    email : a@a.com,
    services : {
      servicekey1 : true,
      servicekey9 : true
    }
  }
}

services : {
  servicekey1 : {
    name : blahserve,
    category : blahbers,
    providers : {
      user1 : true,
      user7 : true
    }
  }
}
```

I want to get the list of user objects for a service. How can this be done with and without angularfire.

I came up with this query (without angularfire) -

```
var refu = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users"); 
var refs = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/services"); 
refs.child("servicekey1/providers").once("value",function(s){
  var users = s.val();
  angular.forEach(users, function(v,k){
    refu.child(k).once("value", function(su){
    console.log(su.val());
    })
  })
});
```

This solves my purpose but I feel there should be a better way to do it , may be with angular fire. Please suggest if there are any other/ better ways to achieve this?

Comment: There's no way to give a arbitrary subset of child ids and get back a collection in a single call. So the way you're doing it is correct, and would be the same pattern with angularfire. If this ends up being an issue, the alternative is to denormalize your data, where the user object is stored in its entirety in the services collection as well. There are pros to this, IE less reads, but there also cons of keeping data in sync, and larger loads if you don't need the data.